# How to remove this shadow border around artborad in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard

[image: Border behind artboard]How do I remove this border around the illustrator artboard? its like a drop shadow arounf the board and it comes out as a white border when I export the file. Ive checked and theres no bleed in my document set up. not sure what to do. Ive attached the image of what im talking about.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. What format are you exporting as?  What software are you using to view it?

Comment: Hello! Im using adobe illustrator  25.2.3 and i want to export it as jpeg but the border shows up in the working screen before i even export

Comment: Does it do this if you make a new document? Is there anything showing in your layers panel? The default artboard does look like this with a thin black border and light grey border on the right. I don't think you can change that, but you really have to zoom in, like 1600% to even see that.

Comment: This is without layers but I figure out that if I export the file and tick 'Use Artboards' then I don't get the white border